# Why does Clojure have "keywords" in addition to "symbols"?

Tags: lisp, clojure, scheme, keyword

I have a passing knowledge of other Lisps (particularly Scheme) from way back. Recently I've been reading about [Clojure](http://clojure.org/). I see that it has both "symbols" and "keywords". Symbols I'm familiar with, but not with keywords.

Do other Lisps have keywords? How are keywords different from symbols other than having different notation (ie: colons)?

Comment: See also: [in Clojure, why have Strings, Keywords AND Symbols?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11655080/405550)

Answer (score 152, accepted):

Here's the [Clojure documentation](https://clojure.org/reference/data_structures#Keywords) for Keywords and Symbols.

> Keywords are symbolic identifiers that evaluate to themselves. They provide very fast equality tests...
>
> Symbols are identifiers that are normally used to refer to something else. They can be used in program forms to refer to function parameters, let bindings, class names and global vars...

Keywords are generally used as lightweight "constant strings", e.g. for the keys of a hash-map or the dispatch values of a multimethod.  Symbols are generally used to name variable and functions and it's less common to manipulate them as objects directly except in macros and such.  But there's nothing stopping you from using a symbol everywhere you use a keyword (if you don't mind quoting them all the time).

The easiest way to see the difference is to read `Keyword.java` and `Symbol.java` in the Clojure source.  There are a few obvious implementation differences.  For example a Symbol in Clojure can have metadata and a Keyword can't.

In addition to single-colon syntax, you can use a double-colon to make a namespace-qualified keyword.

```
user> :foo
:foo
user> ::foo
:user/foo
```

Common Lisp has keywords, as do Ruby and other languages.  They are slightly different in those languages of course.  Some differences between Common Lisp keywords and Clojure keywords:

1. Keywords in Clojure are not Symbols.

   ```
   user> (symbol? :foo)  
   false
   ```
2. Keywords don't belong to any namespace unless you specifically qualify them:

   ```
   user> (namespace :foo)
   nil
   user> (namespace ::foo)
   "user"
   ```

(Thanks [Rainer Joswig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/69545/rainer-joswig) for giving me ideas of things to look at.)

Comment: This explains _what_ the differences are, but not why two different constructs are needed.  Couldn't Clojure have created something with the union of the capabilities of both Keyword and Symbol?

Comment: Keywords are lightweight and have a convenient syntax, I think that's about all there is to it.  The language would work fine without them but they're nice to have and they are very widely used.  You can't have a union of their abilities because Keywords are always self-evaluating (i.e. you can't use them as variable or function names) and Symbols in general can't be always self-evaluating.

Comment: It seems keywords are more useful as keys in hashmaps etc as they don't change once evaluated: `(eval (eval ':a))` vs `(eval (eval ''a))`. Are there other advantages? Performance wise, they are identical?

Comment: (identical? :qwe :qwe) -> true.
(identical? 'qwe 'qwe) -> false. Symbols use interned string inside, so comparison is fast too.

Answer (score 31):

**Common Lisp** has [keyword](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/t_kwd.htm) symbols.

Keywords are symbols, too.

```
(symbolp ':foo) -> T
```

What makes keywords special:

- `:foo` is parsed by the Common Lisp reader as the symbol  `keyword::foo`
- keywords evaluate to themselves:   `:foo` -> `:foo`
- the home package of keyword symbols is the `KEYWORD` package:   `keyword:foo`  ->  `:foo`
- keywords are exported from the package `KEYWORD`
- keywords are constants, it is not allowed to assign a different value

Otherwise keywords are ordinary symbols. So keywords can name functions or have property lists.

Remember: in Common Lisp symbols belong to a package: the [keyword package](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/11_abc.htm). This can be written as:

- `foo`, when the symbol is accessible in the current package
- `foo:bar`, when the symbol `FOO` is exported from the package `BAR`
- `foo::bar`, when the symbol `FOO` is in the package `BAR`

For keyword symbols that means that `:foo`, `keyword:foo` and `keyword::foo` are all the same symbol. Thus the latter two notations are usually not used.

So `:foo` is just parsed to be in the package `KEYWORD`, assuming that giving no package name before the symbol name means by default the `KEYWORD` package.

Answer (score 6):

Keywords are symbols that evaluate to themselves, so you don't have to remember to quote them.

Comment: Is that it? Typing : rather than ' doesn't seem like a big win, especially since : is an extra keypress on most keyboards.

Comment: Well, it's more than just the character, really. Keywords stay keywords after evaluation, while symbols are evaluated to whatever they bind to. It's more like a semantic difference, because they're typically used for different purposes.

Comment: Keywords are not symbols in Clojure

Answer (score 5):

:keywords are also treated specially by many of the collections, allowing for some really convenient syntax.

```
(:user-id (get-users-map))
```

is the same as

```
((get-users-map) :user-id)
```

this makes things just a little more flexable

Comment: This is also true for symbols, ('a {'a 1 'b 2}) => 1 and ({'a 1 'b 2} 'b) => 2.

Answer (score 5):

For keywords, hash values are calculated and cached when the keyword is
first constructed. When looking up a keyword as a hash key, it simply
returns the precomputed hashed value. For strings and symbols, the hash is
recalculated on every lookup.

The why same named keywords are always identical, they contains their own hash values.
As search in maps and sets are made from hash keys this envolves better search efficiency in case of numerous searches, not in the search itself.

Answer (score -1):

**Keywords are global**, symbols are *not*.

This example is written in JavaScript, but I hope it helps to carry the point across.

```js
const foo = Symbol.for(":foo") // this will create a keyword
const foo2 = Symbol.for(":foo") // this will return the same keyword
const foo3 = Symbol(":foo") // this will create a new symbol
foo === foo2 // true
foo2 === foo3 // false
```

When you construct a symbol using the `Symbol` function you get a distinct/private symbol every time. When you ask for a symbol via the `Symbol.for` function, you will get back the same symbol every time.

```clj
(println :foo) ; Clojure
```

```java
System.out.println(RT.keyword(null, "foo")) // Java
```

```js
console.log(System.for(":foo")) // JavaScript
```

These are all the same.

---

Function argument names are local. i.e. not keywords.

```clj
(def foo (fn [x] (println x))) ; x is a symbol
(def bar (fn [x] (println x))) ; not the same x (different symbol)
```

Comment: Why do you use JavaScript examples here? It seems confusing to me.

Comment: @DavidJ. because I port a lot of Clojure code to JavaScript and it maps pretty well. You can also run it in your browser without any hassle. It was the most natural way for me to explain the concept. Also, it adds another dimension to the explanation. So if you happen to know JavaScript you can use that knowledge to map that onto Clojure as you learn more and more. JavaScript is also the most common programming language in the world. It isn't hurting anyone.